# Difference between editions of A Game of Thrones from 2016

Tags: george-r-r-martin, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, textual-history

In 2016, Bantam published a *A Game of Thrones: The Illustrated Edition* with a hard cover, a foreword by John Hodgman, maps by Jeffrey L. Ward and illustrations by Michael Komarck and Michael S. Miller. (See e.g. [Amazon.de](https://www.amazon.de/Game-Thrones-Illustrated-Song-Fire/dp/0553808044/).)

In the same year, Harper Collins UK published *A Game of Thrones. 20th Anniversary Illustrated Edition*, also with a hard cover, a foreword by John Hodgman, maps by Jeffrey L. Ward and illustrations by Michael Komarck and Michael S. Miller. (See e.g. [Amazon.de](https://www.amazon.de/Game-Thrones-20th-Anniversary-Illustrated/dp/0008209103/).)

Both editions are 896 pages long. Are these two editions just the American and the British edition of the exact same book, or are there any differences that I overlooked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**I am inclined to say that they are the same book, just produced under different publishers.**

When [searching](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=A%20Game%20of%20Thrones.%2020th%20Anniversary%20Illustrated%20Edition) on Amazon (in the United States) for "A Game of Thrones: 20th Anniversary Illustrated Edition". I am presented with the two different covers that your searches also provided.

[image: agot amazon search]

You will notice that the Harper cover is shown second even though it is an exact title match while the Bantam "original" edition is listed shown first.

Digging a bit deeper the Harper edition is listed as one of seventy-one other formats for *A Game of Thrones*, while the Bantam is listed as its own work.

[image: agot edition list]

Beyond that the Bantam edition shows a preview with some of the illustrations, while the Harper edition preview reverts back to a standard preview.

As mentioned in the [comments](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/5675/difference-between-editions-of-a-game-of-thrones-from-2016/5734#comment11075_5675), the blurb on the German Amazon site for the Harper edition and on American Amazon for the Bantam are almost an exact match

> Published in celebration of the twentieth anniversary of George R. R. Martin's landmark series, this lavishly illustrated special edition of A Game of Thrones-with gorgeous full-page illustrations in every chapter-revitalizes the fantasy masterpiece that became a cultural phenomenon. [German Amazon]

> Published in celebration of the twentieth anniversary of George R. R. Martin’s landmark series, this lavishly illustrated special edition of A Game of Thrones—featuring gorgeous full-page artwork as well as black-and-white illustrations in every chapter—revitalizes the fantasy masterpiece that became a cultural phenomenon. [American Amazon]

**Beyond that I see no reason why a book by the same author, same foreword, same maps, same illustrator, and same number of pages would differ between publishers beyond the cover.**